Visual Studio 2022 - Connect to existing GitHub Repo
I'm having issues with pushing my local git branches into my GitHub repository in Visual Studio in the git Changes section. I am able to do so using Git Bash just fine and in Visual Studio I can then see those remote branches that I pushed.
The issues comes when trying to push a local branch to Git Hub via Visual Studio. When I click push it opens up a menu wanting me to create a new GitHub repository. I just want to connect to my existing one and then push.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Thanks!
Tried to check my managed connections but GitHub not appearing as an option
enter image description here
